# how to display a div on input fields in jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, tooltip

i'm making a jquery form. Where i need to display a div only on those input fields where i click. (like tool tip.. but not exactly)... ya.. you can call it like datepicker...

Thank you----
**updated**

Javascript:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#months :input').click(function(){
                xpos = $(this).css('left');
                ypos = $(this).css('top');
                var dateField = $(this);

                $('#calender').addClass('calender_visible');
                var m = $('#calender .picker_month :selected').val();
                var y = $('#calender .picker_year :selected').val();


                $('#calender :button').click(function(){
                    dateField.val(m+'/'+y);
                    $('#calender').removeClass('calender_visible');

                })

            })

        });

        </script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .calender_hidden{
        display:none;
    }

.calender_visible{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
width:120px;

    height:50px;
  }
</style>
```

Html:

```
    <input name="month2"  />

    <input name="month3"  />

    <input name="month4"  />

    <input name="month5"  />
    </div>




    <div id="calender" class="calender_hidden" > 

    <select  class="picker_month">
        <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
        <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
        <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
        <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
    </select>

    <select  class="picker_year">
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="close" />
    </div>
```

---

Now the question is... i want to display this small calender only on the div i select... but this doesn't appear under the object i clicked... how i reposition everytime when i click on input fields.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: can we see some html and some code you have tried and maybe some errors your getting if any

Comment: Thank you!... 
this could be more nice if would ask me instead of marking me down. :( . i am new in jquery. looking for help.. i need to display a popup when i click on some input field..ie. button.. anyway.. thank yuo

Comment: I personally did not down vote you however my input still stands we need to see your html and any code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

If you want a datepicker you can use the one in the jquery UI

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: he wasn't asking for a datepicker

Comment: its one of the tags and he said like a date picker. I was simply suggesting he use a library instead of writing the code himself since he didn't have much experience with jquery

Comment: Thank you very much for both of your guys... :) .. really.. .. i like to develop everything myself.. i started learning jquery a week ago.. and i work on this 3 hours daily.. it's really easy... i'm not only practicing this.. i'm working on actual project (my University)...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are trying to capture a click for an input such as a button, or focus for an input such as a text input. Either way capturing event in jQuery is easy:

```
//capture click event
$('input#id').click(function() {
       $('div#id').show();
}
//capture focus event (such as clicking in a text input field)
$('input#id').focus(function() {
       $('div#id').show();
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you should look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) there is dialog() that's probably as close as your gonna get until tooltip is devleoped